# python object() takes no Parameter

Tags: python, oop

While executing this I'm getting error saying :

```
D:\SARFARAZ\Python>Python assignment_01.py   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assignment_01.py", line 35, in <module>
    BankAcc1 = BankAcc('Sarfaraz',12345,50000)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

The code:

```
#Assignment_01 : Class Creation
class BankAcc(object):
    int_rate = 0.7
    balance = 0

    #def **_init_**(self, name, number, balance):  --> error was in this line, I've corrected it now as below
    def __init__(self, name, number, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.balance = balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance

    def add_interest(self):
        self.interest = int_rate * self.balance
        self.balance += self.interest
        return self.balance

'''class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, min_bal):
        BankAccount.__init__(self)
        self.min_bal = 500

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if self.balance - amount < self.min_bal:
            print ("Sorry, minimum balance must be maintained.")
        else:
            BankAccount.withdraw(self, amount)'''

BankAcc1 = BankAcc('Sarfaraz',12345,50000)
BankAcc2 = BankAcc1.withdraw(1000)
print (BankAcc2)
```

I'm trying to create an object and then trying to call the **withdraw()** method
and printing the balance after some amount is withdrawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `__init__` method name:

```
def _init_(self, name, number, balance):
```

You need to use **two** underscores at the start and end.

Without a validly named `__init__` method Python falls back to `object.__init__`, which takes no parameters.

Comment: How could i be so silly to miss that..!!! thanks @Martijn Pieters